# Installing eyed3 in windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, installation, eyed3

trying to install eyed3 under python 2.7.5

I have done a google search and have been following what I found to install eyed3.  The instructions were as follows

1. extract the zip file to a temp folder (filename eyeD3-0.7.3.zip) I
   did using a temp folder on my desktop.
2. In the eyeD3 folder    (under src) rename the **init**.py.in to
   setup.py.  I did not find  _init++.py.in in the eyed3 folder, but
   *init*_.py was,so I assumed this latest version used that file.
3. In the main folder (I  assume eyeD3-0.7.3) run python setup.py.in
   install.  setup.py.in didnot exist, but I ran it anyway and got the
   expected file not found   message, however, setup.py did exist so I
   executed python setup.py install and got the following Traceback

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\New   
   folder\eyeD3-0.7.3\setup.py", line 10, in <module>
   paver.tasks.main()   File "paver-minilib.zip\paver\tasks.py", line
   883, in main File    "paver-minilib.zip\paver\tasks.py", line 851,
   in _launch_pavement  File "pavement.py", line 28, in <module>
   import setuptools    ImportError: No module named setuptools
   ```

a cmd line search of the python 2.7.5 dir and sub-directories did not find setuptools.py, however I did find the following two files

setuptools_build_ext.py and setuptools_extension.py.

Do I need to rename one of these files or do you know what I am doing wrong or what the fix would be?

Thank you

Comment: Where did you find these instructions? That's certainly not what [the official docs](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/installation.html) say to do, and it's a very weird set of things to do for _any_ project.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you got your Python from, it may not have come with [`setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools). In particular, it does *not* come in the standard Windows installers from Python.org.

Some packages' `setup.py` scripts have special code that tries to download and install `setuptools` (or `distribute`) if it's missing, or that bundles in just enough of `setuptools` into the package itself. But not all of them do.

The answer is to [install setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/1.1.3#installing-and-using-setuptools) yourself.

While you're at it, you probably want to also [install pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/), and then you can just `pip install .` from within the directory, or `pip install eyeD3-0.7.3.zip` without unzipping, or even just `pip install eyeD3` without even downloading. (Among other things, it will also download and install any dependencies that eyeD3 might need.)

In fact, the [eyeD3 installation docs](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/index.html#installation) explicitly say "Stable releases of eyeD3 are best installed via `pip`…".

Comment: thank you, I was able to install it using pip.  As an aside, one issue I can see is a source of frustration in at least one response that I got here is stems from that fact that a lot of us window users have not had to use a command line since somewhere around 1995. I am no different, having to really puzzle out the links you sent me. but I did finally.  (We are so use to a nice little grey box with a few next buttons to install our packages).  Regardless, I was able to do it with your help.  Thank you.

Comment: @DonThomson: That's exactly why many packages have official Windows binary installers, and Christoph Gohlke makes [binary packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) available for many more. Unfortunately, he can't package everything in the universe, so if you want to access the full wealth of PyPI you eventually need the command line. Really, if you're writing code, you should be able to understand the command line anyway. Unfortunately, all the documentation is written for Unix, typically with comments like "things may be a little different on Windows", which really doesn't help…

Comment: @Don Thomson: If the answer given by helped you in solving your problem then accept his answer or upvote it.